# narrowing input types causes widening of output type

Tags: typescript

Here is a piece of a functional Maybe Option in TypeScript. This function takes a value, applies a mapping function to it, and returns the result. If the value is null or undefined, the mapping function isn't called and Undefined is returned.

```
function mapA<T, U>(source: T, selector: (v: NonNullable<T>) => U) {
    return (source == null || source === undefined) ? undefined : selector(source!);
}
const mapAResult = mapA(2, i => i * i); // Type is number | undefined
```

OK, so now I try to insist that the mapping function never return a null or undefined by changing the return type of the selector to `NonNullable`. When I mouse over `mapBResult` it says the type is `{} | undefined`. That seems weird to me. I think I'm saying that the function can return fewer possible values than the function above, and yet the result type is wider. Shouldn't fewer possible inputs lead to fewer possible outputs?

```
function mapB<T, U>(source: T, selector: (v: NonNullable<T>) => NonNullable<U>) {
    return (source == null || source === undefined) ? undefined : selector(source!);
}
const mapBResult = mapB(2, i => i * i); // Type is { } | undefined
```

Secondly, why do I need to put an exclamation point at the end of `source!`. Shouldn't control flow analysis know it isn't null at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OK, so now I try to insist that the mapping function never return a null or undefined by changing the return type of the selector to NonNullable

This isn't really what `NonNullable` does.

What you want is this:

```
function mapB<T, U extends object | string | number | boolean>(source: T | null | undefined, selector: (v: T) => U) {
    return (source == null || source === undefined) ? undefined : selector(source);
}
const mapBResult = mapB(2, i => i * i); // Type is number
```

Comment: wow that was fast. maybe you can explain why NonNullable doesn't do what I expect?

Comment: You *could* use `NonNullable` if you wanted to, but I think the problem is that there was no inference site for `U`... maybe `function mapB<T, U>(source: T, selector: (v: NonNullable<T>) => U & NonNullable<U>): U | undefined { ... }` would work?

Comment: I tried the NonNullable like you said and couldn't get it to work. Ryan's answer is best, and is easy to understand.

Comment: The short version is that `NonNullable<U>` is not a good inference site for `U` because it's a conditional type alias and will be eagerly resolved to one of its output types. The only time it'd be able to produce an inference is if it were instantiated with another type parameter.